# How to display Android SearchView suggestions in a customized view

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, searchview, android-searchmanager

[Amazon app search suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlPie.jpg)

The Search suggestions in Amazon app has rows that span the full width of the display, and have an upward pointing arrow on the right and a cross mark on the left.

I am getting default row look upon using Android Searchview functionality(Just content from query result). How can I make it look customized, like the one in Amazon app. Does Android provide a functionality to hookup custom adapters etc ? OR does the whole SearchView have to be implemented to achieve such customized looks.

Answer (score 0):

There is this method [SearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setSuggestionsAdapter(android.widget.CursorAdapter)). You could use custom adapter to change a layout of suggestions.